# Silverlight DragDropTarget - just copy, not move

Tags: .net, silverlight, drag-and-drop

I'd like to ask, how can I in Silverlight just copy an item with drag&drop, not move, if I'm using the DragDropTargets?

---

I've fount that: [Silverlight Toolkit Drag Drop (Part 2): Customizing Drag and Drop Behavior](http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/10/silverlight-drag-drop-support-part-2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to set the AllowedSourceEffects property for the source *DragDropTarget element, like here:

```
<toolkit:PanelDragDropTarget VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" AllowedSourceEffects="Copy">
 <!-- here is a panel -->
</toolkit:PanelDragDropTarget>
```